# Get MAX Date using SQL in Databricks

Tags: sql, databricks

I'm having trouble producing a sql query to get the max date of this case_version_status_dt column from the results in the attached image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXeKA.png)

I tried using this example query:

`

```
SELECT distinct
  cm.case_id,
  cm.user_case_id,
  cmr.CREATE_USER_ID,
  cm.CASE_MANAGER_USER_ID,
  date_format(case_version_status_dt, "MM/dd/yyyy") as case_version_status_dt,
  date_format(cmr.CASE_VERSION_MILESTONE_DT, "MM/dd/yyyy") as CASE_VERSION_MILESTONE_DT
 
 from dsams.case_master as cm
  
  left join dsams.case_usage_indicator as cu on cm.case_usage_indicator_cd = cu.case_usage_indicator_cd
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT max(case_version_status_dt) as case_version_status_dt, case_id, case_version_id,CUSTOMER_REQUEST_ID,case_version_status_cd,case_version_type_cd FROM dsams.case_version v GROUP BY case_id,case_version_id,CUSTOMER_REQUEST_ID,case_version_status_cd,case_version_type_cd) cv ON cm.case_id = cv.case_id
  --left join dsams.case_version as cv on cm.case_id = cv.case_id
  left join dsams.case_version_milestone as cvm on cv.case_version_id = cvm.case_version_id
  left join dsams.case_milestone_revision as cmr on cvm.case_milestone_id = cmr.case_milestone_id
  left join dsams.milestone as m on cvm.milestone_id = m.milestone_id
  left join dsams.CUSTOMER_ORGANIZATION co on co.CUSTOMER_ORGANIZATION_ID = cm.CUSTOMER_ORGANIZATION_ID
  left join dsams.CUSTOMER_ORGANIZATION_SERVICE cos on cos.CUSTOMER_ORGANIZATION_ID = co.CUSTOMER_ORGANIZATION_ID
  left join dsams.CUSTOMER_SERVICE_TYPE cst on cst.CUSTOMER_SERVICE_TYPE_ID = cos.CUSTOMER_SERVICE_TYPE_ID
  left join dsams.CUSTOMER_REQUEST c on c.CUSTOMER_REQUEST_ID = cv.CUSTOMER_REQUEST_ID
  left join dsams.CASE_VERSION_STATUS cvs on cvs.case_version_status_cd = cv.case_version_status_cd
  left join dsams.CASE_VERSION_TYPE cvt on cvt.CASE_VERSION_TYPE_CD = cv.case_version_type_cd

where  cm.user_case_id = "AJPTAB" and
       m.MILESTONE_ID = "MILAP" and
       cst.SERVICE_TYPE_TITLE_NM = "Navy" and
       cv.CASE_VERSION_TYPE_CD in ("A","M","B","I") and
       cm.case_usage_indicator_cd in ("C","P") and
       cm.SECURITY_ASSISTANCE_PROGRAM_CD ="FMS" and
       cm.CASE_MASTER_STATUS_CD in ("N","P") and
       cv.case_version_status_cd not in ("CL","X")
order by  case_version_status_dt
```

Comment: You probably need to join on id and date.

Comment: What kind of trouble? Do you have an example of what you'd expect?